# Returning 'null' to my server

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first development using html/javascript and since my previous career was programming aircraft, it all seems very strange!

So ... I picked up a Raspberry Pi and decided to develop server/client software so I can control my garden lighting and water features from my mobile using my wifi system.

I can now turn on and off all my lights and pumps in the garden from any mobile.

I am now refining the software and this simple item has me stumped. When the user switches on a water feature, I want the server to switch off the water feature when the minutes set by the user has expired.

The html has:

```
<p>
<input type="checkbox" id="waterFeatureZenGarden">
<label for="waterFeatureZenGarden">Water Feature Zen Garden</label>
<input type="number" min="1" max="180" value="60" id="waterFeatureZenGardenTimer">
</p>
```

my Java Script on the html page has:

```
<script>
var socket = io(); //load socket.io-client and connect to the host that serves the page

window.addEventListener("load", function(){ //when page loads
  var gateStatus = document.getElementById("gate");
  var getWFZG = document.getElementById("WaterFeatureZenGarden");
  var getWLZG = document.getElementById("WallLightsZenGarden");
  var getLLZG = document.getElementById("LanternLightsZenGarden");

  getWFZG.addEventListener("change", function() { 
    socket.emit("WaterFeatureZenGarden", Number(this.checked));
    socket.emit("WaterFeatureZenGardenTimer", Number(this.value));
   });
```

My server code receives the socket.emit events as below:

```
  socket.on('waterFeatureZenGarden', function(data) {
    wFZGvalue = data;
    if (wFZGvalue != onWFZG.readSync()) { 
      onWFZG.writeSync(wFZGvalue); //turn pump on/off
    }
  });

  socket.on('waterFeatureZenGardenTimer', function(data) { 
    wFZGTvalue = data;
    // code will go here to start timer for how long the pump will run
    console.log(wFZGTvalue); // added this line to see what wFZGTvalue is
  });
```

The console shows that wFZGTvalue is 'null'.

What have I got wrong? Is it server side or client side?

If I change the client side js to:

```
socket.emit("waterFeatureZenGardenTimer", 100);
```

The server receives '100' so it seems I am not accessing the html element correctly yet I am getting the check boxes for all on and off functions.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 2):

When you access `this.value` inside of the listener, `this` refers to:

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="waterFeatureZenGarden">
```

And that has no value.

You might wanna get the timer:

```
  var timer = document.getElementById("WaterFeatureZenGardenTimer");
```

And then take the timers value:

```
 socket.emit("timer", timer.value);
```

---

Now on the serverside you could define a global variable that holds your timer:

```
  let timer;
```

Then when you receive the clients timing request, you could kill the ongoing timeout and set a new one:

```
 if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
 timer = setTimeout(function(){
   onWFZG.writeSync("0");
 }, +userValue * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: About the server side part: this might be a good time to introduce hoisting. If you are using `timer` as a global variable, its position is very important. (`let` behaves differently from `var` in that respect). Also, passing a digit `0` to  `writeSync` seems the more logical approach, rather than a string. Finally I think that the plus sign before `userValue` is a typo?

Comment: @bram vanroy no not really. `let` is also hoisted, but it has a *temporal deadzone*, however the code in the handler will definetly be exuted *after* the timer definition, regardless of its position. We cant tell wether `writeSync` takes a string or not, i think both versions are reasonable. And no, the plus sign is a *unary plus operator* cause i hate inferred typecasting

Comment: Jonas, Many thanks, that fixed it. Looks like I need to read more about 'this.xxx' as clearly I haven't grasped that. With all the other comments from you and Bram, I will take on board and make some changes.

Answer (score 0):

In your window.addEventListener you need to get input value like

```
var timerValue = document.getElementById("waterFeatureZenGardenTimer").value;
```

and then pass this timerValue as

```
socket.emit("WaterFeatureZenGardenTimer", timerValue);
```

Comment: Kalleshwar, thanks for your input, just tried it and that works to! It seems to me that I need to learn more about html as in many ways, JS more or less fits into the type of code I am already familiar with, just need to get used to the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Cool project! A few things. Since you are just starting to learn JS, it might be better to immediately hop on the ES6 boat - it is the newest iteration in Javascript and it introduces some cool stuff such as arrow functions, constants, OO, and so on. In addition, if you want to run code when DOM is loaded, use `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded")`. Finally, in JS it is common to use lowerCamelCase names for functions and variables.

On to your code, it seems you want the value of the timer - and not of the checkbox, which `this` refers to, so add a variable for that as well. I'm not sure why you are parsing the checkbox checked as a Number(), though, but I left it there because I'm not sure why you want that.

```
const socket = io(); 

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const gateStatus = document.querySelector("#gate"),
        wfzg = document.querySelector("#WaterFeatureZenGarden"),
        wfzgt = document.querySelector("#WaterFeatureZenGardenTimer"),
        wlzg = document.querySelector("#WallLightsZenGarden"),
        llzg = document.querySelector("#LanternLightsZenGarden");

  getWFZG.addEventListener("change", function() { 
    socket.emit("WaterFeatureZenGarden", Number(this.checked));
    socket.emit("WaterFeatureZenGardenTimer", wfzgt.value);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Bram. Will look into ES6 boat. Will that mean a complete change in code or just minor adjustments. As for the reason why parsing the checkbox checked as a Number(), that is because I learned  how to set a server and client from www.w3schools.com.